# Find which file contain a particular keyword using `grep`

Tags: files, grep

Suppose I know I have to change `myhostname = abc.domain.lcl` to `myhostname = abc.domain.glbl` directive but I don't know in which file exactly the directive `myhostname` is in (i.e., say I have never heard of `/etc/postfix/main.cf`).

I need to change the directive myhostname.

Problem: I don't know in which file the directive is in.

Question: How can I find out the file name which contains the directive?

Comment: `grep` recursively...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
grep -Hr "<keyword>" <directory>
```

It recursively searches files under `<directory>` and prints matches with filenames.

Comment: The `-r` flag implies `-H` (from the man page: `This is the default when there is more than one file to search.`). i.e. you don't need `-Hr`, just `-r`.